# How to select data from this json using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, json, select

```
var tz = {"US": [123, 456, 784], "UK": [456, 461, 953]};
```

An I get country code from web page's form.

e.g.

```
var countryCode = $('#country option:selected').val(); // Now "countryCode" is UK
```

Now I want to get the array data of `"UK"`. e.g. `[456, 461, 953]`

How can I write the code? Thanks.

Comment: `tz` does not contain JSON data. It is a normal object literal. It is only JSON if it is a **string** (and only contains valid data types of course).

Answer (score 8):

Since you have the value in a variable, use the bracket notation:

```
tz[countryCode]
```

or if you know the value beforehand, this should work too.

```
tz.UK
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is looking for the answer of the question in the title:

If you actually have JSON data:

```
var tz = '{"US": [123, 456, 784], "UK": [456, 461, 953]};';
```

Then you use the `parseJSON` method to turn it into a Javascript object, then you can access the object:

```
var countryData = $.parseJSON(tz);
var countryArray = countryData[countryCode];
```